# How do I make a smart contract call a function of another smart contract that requires payment?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract lotteryBot {

    address owner;
    address casino;
    scratchoff _t;

    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
        casino = 0xGG4767f31960394B6c5770478e1GrB2Av97f0Ce8;
        _t = scratchoff(casino);
    }

    function fundBot() public payable{
    }


    function getTicket() private {
        (bool success,) = casino.call{value: 2 ether}("");
        require(success, "Fail at stage one");
        _t.buyTicket();
    }

    function playLottery() private {
        _t.play(2);
    }

    function killCasino() public {
        while(true){
            getTicket();
            playLottery();
        }
    }

    function retrieveFunds() public{
        (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(success, "Not paid");
    }
}

abstract contract scratchoff{
    function buyTicket() public virtual;
    function play(uint num) public virtual;
    function takePayout() public virtual;

}
```

The *getTicket()* function requires 2 ether to be transacted with.  How do I transact with this other contract from this one?  I tried calling the function without paying the casino contract in it, and that didn't work either.  Also, it seems like the require is throwing me an error in this contract, not the second contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got a simple example for you, hope you understand it and implement it, in your own contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

contract a {
    bool public recived; //by default false. 
    function recive2ether() external payable {
        require(msg.value >= 2 ether);
        recived = true;
    }
}

interface ainterface {
    function recive2ether() external payable;
}

contract b {
    ainterface A;
    constructor (ainterface _A) {
        A = ainterface(_A);
    }

    function sendEthtoA() public payable {
        A.recive2ether{value: msg.value}(); 
    }
}
```